# Regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I have regular expression but I don't know how to use it in Java.  This is the Java code,

```
String inputString = "he is in cairo on 20-2-20 12  and he will be here on JANUARY 20 2013  the expected time to arrived is 100: 00 ";
String pattern = " ";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = pt.matcher(inputString);
String resultString=null;
if(m.find()) {
    resultString = m.replaceAll(" ");
}
System.out.println(resultString);
```

The requirements are:

1. remove any spaces substitutes by single space.
2. the data format like this `dd-mm-yyyy`.
3. if there is any spaces between numbers remove it just between numbers.
4. the month JANUARY maybe come in this format: `JAN`.

The expected output is:

```
he is in cairo on 20-2-2012  and he will be here on 20-01-2013  the expected time to arrived is 100:00
```

I have used this:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)-(\\d+)?\\s*(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)").matcher(inputString);
String resultString=null;
String temp_str=null;
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.groupCount()==3) {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        int second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
        String month = m.group(3);
        System.out.println("three parts");
        temp_str=m.replaceAll("\\1-\\2-\\3");
        System.out.println(temp_str);
    } else {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        String month = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("two parts");
       temp_str=m.replaceAll("\\1-\\2-\\3");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't ask us to convert the code. Because with that, you have bound the answerer to know both the languages used in conversion. Rather just tell what you want to do? Your input, and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks I found the solution as follows :

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{1,2}) ([0-9]{4})").matcher(inputString);
String resultString = null;
String temp_str = null;
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.groupCount() == 3) {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        int second = Integer.valueOf(m.group(2));
        String month = m.group(3);
        System.out.println("three parts" + month);
        if (month.matches("Jan"))
        {
            System.out.println("three parts wael");
            temp_str = m.replaceAll(first + "-" + second + "-" + "JANUARY");
        }
        System.out.println(temp_str);
    } 
    else {
        int first = Integer.valueOf(m.group(1));
        String month = m.group(2);
        System.out.println("two parts");
        temp_str = m.replaceAll("\\1-\\2-\\3");
    }
}
```